# Canvas is null error in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

i have this code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <style type="text/css">
 canvas{border:#666 1px solid;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
        context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
        playerimage = new Image(),
        x = canvas.width / 2, //align to centre of the screen
        y = canvas.height / 2, //same as above
        speed = 5, //speed for the player to move at
        width = 50, //width of the player
        height = 50; //height of the player

  function init() {


   playerimage.src = "ninja.png"; //path to the image to use for the player
   canvas.addEventListener("keypress", update);
  }

  function update(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 38) {
        y -= speed; //going up
    }
    if (event.keyCode == 40) {
        y += speed; //going down
    }
    if (event.keyCode == 37) {
        x -= speed; //going left
    }
    if (event.keyCode == 39) {
        x += speed; //going right
    }
    render();
}

function render() {
   // context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.drawImage(playerimage, x, y, width, height);

}
   </script>
 </head>
    <body onload="init();">
   <button onclick="init();">Draw</button>
    <canvas id="Mycanvas" width="550" height="400"></canvas>
   </body>  
  </html>
```

the javascript console always give me canvas is null error

Comment: BTW, use a semicolon (`;`) instead of the comma (`,`) to separate the commands in javascript.

Comment: @PetrR. - Not in a multiline `var` statement that declares multiple variables.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There are two problems with the following line of code:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
```

1. It runs before the canvas element has been parsed and added to the DOM.
2. It uses the wrong ID.

Change it to:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("Mycanvas"),
```

...and move the whole `<script>` block to the end of the body, just before `</body>`.

Answer (score 2):

Your id of the canvas in html does not match the one you use in

```
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
```

Correct HTML should be:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="550" height="400"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are butting the script tag in the head, but it in the body tag at the end of it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).